# Loops in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, csv, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap data from this website to obtain a table of all patents: 
http://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/wopublish-search/public/patents?1&query=*:*&lang=en#
I just want to include ID, Name and address of the applicant, Name and address of the inventor(s), and Citations. 
I use BeautifulSoup and have been able to scrap the first page. I need to collect all patents data from this page. Any idea how to scrap the rest of the pages?
Here is the code that I have:

```
import re
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/wopublish-search/public/patents?2&query=*:*&lang=en#"
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' }

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
 for id in soup.find_all("span", class_="rs-AFNB_ORI"):
# print id.text
url = "http://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/wopublish-search/public/detail/patents?id=ID" + id.text
# time.sleep(1)
r= requests.get(url, headers = headers)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
names = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-md-10 product-form-details")
nameAndId = names[2].text.split(":")
citations = names[names.__len__() - 1]
data = []
table = citations.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table-bordered'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])  # Get rid of empty values

print ("ID: " + id.text + " Name: " + nameAndId[0] + " Address: " + nameAndId[1])
for d in data:
    print (d[2])
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the URL of the website changes,

```
first_standard = abc #url till the page number (1,2,3)
final_standard = efg #url after the  number
for i in range (n+1): #n is the number of pages:
 URL = first_standard + str(i) + final_standard
 #your code to scrap
```

The general idea is to change the URL as the page number increases 
Link to code I had created
https://github.com/susmitpy/UNIQUE-PYTHON-PROGRAMS/blob/master/buyer_price.py
Myparse is custom module I created. All it does is takes the link then uses urllib to request it and then bs4 to make a soup

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python. I have tried to follow your suggestion, but I can not solve my problem. Still, I have been only able to scrap the first page. This is my code:                                                            
pdki1 = "http://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/wopublish-search/public/detail/patents?id=IDP00201701019" #url till the page number (1,2,3)
pdki2 = "http://pdki-indonesia.dgip.go.id/wopublish-search/public/detail/patents?id=IDP00201705344" #url after the  number
for i in range (2+1): #n is the number of pages:
 URL = pdki1 + str(i) + pdki2 #my previous codes

Comment: Try scrapy, it is a Web spider, it visits the webpages of a given domain. Try this website to learn it: https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html